Calculating Adjusted Durations Dynamically in Power Query or DAX Based on Time Ranges Power Bi
I have the following Dataset
State is the different machine states available.
calculated duration is the number of seconds spent in each state.
time is the start time of each machine state.
I want to calculate the total time spent in each machine state, I filter my data from 6 AM to 6 AM.
The problem is adding those seconds that are not taken in consideration because the start time was prior to 6 AM.
For example, I need to take in consideration the 3 Hours with 35 minutes that the machine was in processing (Sample Data)

I have tried adding time difference columns but have not been able to make it work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You want to calculate what exactly? Please provide sample input and sample desired data with methodology to get from input to output

I want to calculate the duration of events from 6 am to 6 am.
I calculate processing the following way
Processing=
CALCULATE(
SUM('Machine_States'[calculated_duration]),
FILTER(
'Machine_States',
CONTAINSSTRING('Machine_States'[state], "processing")
)
)
The problem is, there is events in my data that start time is 5:40 AM and end time of 9:35 AM, Since i am slicing my start time from 6AM the event will not be filtered,  I want to be able to SUM the time from 6 AM to 9:35, hope that makes sense
